# WoW "exportInterfaceFiles code" syntax for warcraft 1.12 client

Tags: xml, syntax, lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I was looking at the wowwiki and was able to extract cata's interface files to look at their code, but am unable to do so using the "exportInterfaceFiles code" syntax in the console on the 1.12 client. If anybody knows how, it would be greatly appreciated, as I'd like to look into creating an addon or two for vanilla for funzies mostly.

Also if anyone possibly has a reference to the 1.12 warcraft API that would be much appreciated. Anything else you feel I should know about the process of creating addons for 1.12 would be greatly appreciated since the documentation seems to be hard to come by. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://wow.go-hero.net/framexml/builds have history down to 1.1.2.4115. For historic data on API, [Wowpedia](http://wowpedia.org/API)/Wowwiki itself will do, just rewind relevant pages back to late 2004 - start of 2005 revisions.